# How to align text within dijitTextbox?

Tags: css, dojo, xpages, dijit.form

I need the typed text be aligned vertically middle with left padding (as well as placeholder text)

See picture below:
[image]

Here is a piece of my xPage code:

```
<xe:djTextBox id="djTextBoxSearch"
    style="width:100%;height:60px;">
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="placeholder" value="Please enter a name to search...">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:djTextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default vertical alignment is centered. You can edit margin-left/right. If you additionally want to edit the vertical position, you can use the commented code.

```css
input[type='text']{
  height : 100px;
  width : 200px;
  padding : 0 0 0 30px; 
  /* padding : 20px 0 0 0; //to change the vertical positon */
  text-align : left;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
```